# Phaser Game Development XDK

Tags: intel-xdk, phaser-framework

I am using xdk for phaser html 5 game development.
I am using sample click counter from their website but its not working. Can someone help me?
Here is the code below:

```
/* globals Phaser:false */
// create BasicGame Class
BasicGame = {

};

// create Game function in BasicGame
BasicGame.Game = function (game) {
};

var counter = 0;
// set Game function prototype
BasicGame.Game.prototype = {

    init: function () {
        // set up input max pointers
        this.input.maxPointers = 1;
        // set up stage disable visibility change
        this.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true;
        // Set up the scaling method used by the ScaleManager
        // Valid values for scaleMode are:
        // * EXACT_FIT
        // * NO_SCALE
        // * SHOW_ALL
        // * RESIZE
        // See http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.ScaleManager.html for full document
        this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
        // If you wish to align your game in the middle of the page then you can
        // set this value to true. It will place a re-calculated margin-left
        // pixel value onto the canvas element which is updated on orientation /
        // resizing events. It doesn't care about any other DOM element that may
        // be on the page, it literally just sets the margin.
        this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
        this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
        // Force the orientation in landscape or portrait.
        // * Set first to true to force landscape. 
        // * Set second to true to force portrait.
        this.scale.forceOrientation(false, true);
        // Sets the callback that will be called when the window resize event
        // occurs, or if set the parent container changes dimensions. Use this 
        // to handle responsive game layout options. Note that the callback will
        // only be called if the ScaleManager.scaleMode is set to RESIZE.
        this.scale.setResizeCallback(this.gameResized, this);
        // Set screen size automatically based on the scaleMode. This is only
        // needed if ScaleMode is not set to RESIZE.
        this.scale.updateLayout(true);
        // Re-calculate scale mode and update screen size. This only applies if
        // ScaleMode is not set to RESIZE.
        this.scale.refresh();

    },

    preload: function () {

        // Here we load the assets required for our preloader (in this case a 
        // background and a loading bar)
        this.load.image('logo', 'asset/phaser.png');
    },

    create: function () {
        // Add logo to the center of the stage
        this.logo = this.add.sprite(
            this.world.centerX, // (centerX, centerY) is the center coordination
            this.world.centerY,
            'logo');
        // Set the anchor to the center of the sprite
        this.logo.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
        this.logo.inputEnabled = true;
        this.logo.events.onInputDown.add(onClickListener, this);

        //no add text on screen to check click counter
        this.counterLabel = this.add.text(250, 16, '' , {fill:'FFFFFF'});


    },

    onClickListener: function() {
        counter++;
    this.counterLabel.text = "You clicked " + counter + " times!";
    },

    gameResized: function (width, height) {

        // This could be handy if you need to do any extra processing if the 
        // game resizes. A resize could happen if for example swapping 
        // orientation on a device or resizing the browser window. Note that 
        // this callback is only really useful if you use a ScaleMode of RESIZE 
        // and place it inside your main game state.

    }

};
```

It is throwing this Exception:

> this.logo.events.onInputDown.add(onClickListener, this);

Comment: Have you checked if `asset/phaser.png` is correct and file exists? I suggest too to check the directory where server is serving from if you have any.

Comment: i am using xdk i dont think so there is any server which i need to start/stop manually ide should take care of that

Comment: I understand. Another information you can provide is the exception. The code you posted is the code that produces the exception but not the exception itself. Doesn't xdk give an error in text?

Comment: Also, I talked about checking the path because usually it's `assets` in plural. Just in case it's misspelled.

Comment: hi         this.logo.events.onInputDown.add(onClickListener); is the error 'onClickListener' is not defined. (W117) and sory, yes phaser.png is loading no issue with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `onClickListener` is sitting in `BasicGame.Game.prototype` you should get it from `this`:

```
this.logo.events.onInputDown.add(this.onClickListener, this);
```

Comment: Hurray compiled... but i cant see the text You clicked " + counter + " times!";

Comment: how do i pass text variable to that function?

Comment: About the text, everything seems correct to me. You should put a breakpoint at `this.counterLabel.text = ...` to see at least if the text is created correctly (if it proves difficult, separate the code with `var text = "..." + counter + "..."`). About passing text you can use both instance variables (`this.logo`) or variables in closures (`counter`). You are already doing that.

Comment: sad i am new to all this xdk stuff ... :'( can you point me to some reference learning resource Thanks for helping anwyays...

Comment: Sorry to inform that makes two of us. From what I have read, XDK uses Chrome Dev Tools (if not try to enable CDT) and when you debug you use its debugger (that's good news). [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) you can find instructions.

Comment: i managed to get it working, somewhow there i no error and text is not getting added.